# Allow users outside of local network to view my XAMPP website

Tags: php, xampp

I'm using my laptop as a local server to developer a PHP website. I want my client's to be able to enter my IP address or `ServerName` in a browser and view the website which is hosted on my XAMPP server.

Currently, my colleagues can view the website because they're on the same network as I am. How can I allow my client access who of course works elsewhere.

Through my research I think the relevant files I have are `httpd-vhosts`, `httpd-xampp` and a `httpd-conf` one directory above the aforementioned files.

Comment: This depends on your network, if you have a router you could configure it to forward all requests on port 80 to your internal ip. You may also need to setup a virtual host using `httpd-vhosts`. If you want the clients to be able to use a more userfriendly name then I guess they would have to add an entry in their `/etc/hosts` file to point to your ip.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your site globally. You have to enable port forwarding in your router.
Follow below steps.

- Login into your router (See manufacturer manual for url to log in )
- Look for 'Virtual Server' like Link or menu
- Select Protocol TCP/UDP ,
- PORT : 80, Private PORT: 80, Private IP 
  your_local_ip_address(findout by ipconfig in windows cmd and ifconfig
  in linux terminal)
- type my ip in google and get your IP address.
- Put this ip in browser from anywhere in world

Comment: Is there a way to do it for `https://` that would not involve the above method? Using Port 443 instead?

Comment: You have to uncomment 'LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so' line in httpd.conf